# Invoking Calendar on Droid X (FroYo)

Tags: android

As of the FroYo update, none of the "standard" intents for invoking the Calendar seem to work on the Droid X.  I'm hoping that someone out there has figured out the right App/Activity pair to pull up the calendar, ideally in Agenda view.

You don't need to tell me that this is outside of the official Android API, and thus not an appropriate action to take.  I know this, and I'll gladly use the documented API as soon as one exists.  In the meantime I'm interested in providing my users the capabilities they need, even if that means going with expedience over official correctness.

Comment: have you tried using any of the apps that browse system intents to find out what it is?  Like ADW launcher for example, then you can find the right calendar intent and make a special case for droid x

Comment: I'll give it a try next time I have a Droid X in hand.  I tried a few other tools to try to browse the Activites, but none of them had quite the right mojo.  It looks like ADW might do a better job.  Thx!

Answer (score 1):

That's what happens when you use private APIs :)

Comment: Thank you Romain.  You are, of course, in a position to help make it an official API, at which point I (and many other developers) will switch to using the official API.  In the meantime, I'll suffer whatever slings and arrows are required to give my users the functionality they need.